# How to get a list of Multiple Selected Items and output their Values as an Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am teaching myself how to code. My first project is a webApp using Apps Script. I've managed to complete most of it on my own except for one thing... *I can't seem to output the items from a Multiple Select box into a comma separated array of values.*

Currently, I've managed to return a single value when only one of the list items is selected. **Reference:** [example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFGsc.jpg)

But if I choose more than one, nothing happens. Reference: [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFZbg.jpg)

Essentially, what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

If... *Bill and Mary]* ... are selected from a list, their corresponding ages are output as... *{33,44}*.
Or if... *[Bill, Mary, and Joe]* ...are selected, the result is *{33,44,21}*.

The data is pulled from a single sheet with 2 columns ('Staff' & 'Ages'). The list is also dynamically infinite.

In case my request is confusing, [this resource](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/select/multi-selected.php) clearly demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve but I just can't seem to crack it.

Hopefully this advanced community can help me solve this challenge.

Now, here's the Code.gs and Javascript for reference.

(**NOTE:** I'm looking for a Javascript solution only please. Also, pardon my formatting of this virgin post.)

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Values");
  var posts = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var postListArray = posts.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
    tmp.posts = postListArray;
      return tmp.evaluate();
}

function getAges(uStaff){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Values");
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
  var staffList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var agesList = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; }); 
  var position = staffList.indexOf(uStaff);  
      if(position > -1){
          return agesList[position];
        } else {
          return 'Invalid';
      }  
}
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("staff").addEventListener("change",getRecs);

function getRecs(){
  var uStaff = document.getElementById("staff").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateAges).getAges(uStaff);    
}

function updateAges(ages){
  document.getElementById("age").value = ages;  
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <select id="staff" multiple>
        <?!= posts; ?>
      </select>
      <label for="staff" style="font-size: 20px;">Staff</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input type="text" id="age" class="validate" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code too?

Comment: Hey @Addis I've added the HTML code as requested.

Comment: Hi @cooper, I actually came across that question in my searches. And I assure you, you can probably find many more that may appear to be duplicates. In fact, there are at least 8 posts that I've saved while browsing this forum as a non-member. Joining the forum and asking for help was my absolute second to last resort. The last option is paying someone for their time to teach me something that is probably an easy solution for most of the advanced members in this community. But I'll cross that bridge if I get there.

Comment: Your `doGet()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- `HTMLSelectElement.value` only returns the first selected value.

#### Solution:

- Use `HTMLSelectElement.selectedOptions` to get all selected `HTMLOptionElement` value

#### Snippet#1:

```
var uStaff = [...(document.getElementById("staff").selectedOptions)]
                        .map(e=>e.value);//uStaff is a array of staffs. eg ['Bill', 'Mary']
```

You should then modify your [`getAges` server function to work with a array argument instead of a single value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization). Alternatively, You should pass the whole data as 2D array to client side, use `Map` to get the `age`:

#### Snippet#2:

*Server side:*

```
function getData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Values");
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
  return data;
}
```

*Client side:*

```
document.getElementById("staff").addEventListener("change",getRecs);
var map = null;
function getRecs(){
  if(!map) {//call server if data is not retrieved previously
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateAges).getData()
  } else {updateAges()};    
}
function updateAges(arr){
  if(!map) map = new Map(arr);//map of [[staffs,ages]]
  let uStaff = document.getElementById("staff").selectedOptions;
  let ages = [...uStaff].map(staff=>map.get(staff.value)).join();
  document.getElementById("age").value = ages;  
}
```

#### References:

- [HTMLSelectElement § Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties)
- [Global object Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First I've added the doGet() function to my question. Second, I implemented your response using the alternative Snippet#2. However, it doesn't seem to be returning the {ages}. The output looks like [this](https://imgur.com/UAZjZMm). I'm sure I missed something.

Comment: @Hans Fixed`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: Thanks a lot @TheMaster. Everything is working perfectly now!